# How can I make C# Xamarin.Android app run at phone start-up?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have been trying to get an app to run when phone starts, and eventually run app when I press `KeyCode.CameraButton`. I am using a class called `BootReceiver`, inherited from `BroadcastReceiver`. Here is my class:

```cs
namespace ColorPoint.Xamarin.XAndroid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
    public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    { 
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Intent serviceStart = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
            context.StartActivity(serviceStart);                
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment the app restarts when broadcast received. I run this from `adb` command prompt to emulate boot up and phone restarts!

```sh
adb -s device-or-emulator-id shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Here is my manifest file, not sure if its correct at all!

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="ColorPoint.Xamarin.XAndroid" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <application android:label="Rexson Barcode Scanner" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <activity android:name="MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:exported="false" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</manifest>
```

Need to go through this step by step but can't debug it very well, just so weird how phone resets when I emulate boot up!

I just tried a manual reboot and app tried to start but said `unfortunately [myapp] has stopped working` then phone reboots again.

Seems like it tries to open but crashes immediatley, then reboots phone.

Found this from another example but same thing, just reboots phone..

```cs
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionBootCompleted)
    {
        bool autoRestart = false;
        var sp = context.GetSharedPreferences("preferences", FileCreationMode.Private);
        autoRestart = sp.GetBoolean("autoRestart", false);
        if (autoRestart)
        {
            Intent serviceStart = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
            serviceStart.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            context.StartActivity(serviceStart);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the [`ActivityFlags.NewTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) flag to the intent because you are launching an activity outside of an activity context.

The crash is because a `Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException` is generated by the boot receiver.

The solution:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{ 
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent serviceStart = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
        serviceStart.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        context.StartActivity(serviceStart);                
    }
}
```

Comment: Have tried that now but still getting the "...has stopped working" dialog on reboot

Comment: do I need to call anything from MainActivity?

Comment: That should be it, no more logic needed. That worked perfectly fine on my phone.

Comment: yea cool good to know, Im going to try open app with camera button now, maybe wont crash like that