# Start an app automatically on device boot up in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

After a lot of research on Google, I cannot find a proper guide on how to start a mobile app on device boot up in Xamarin Forms.

Basically I have created a mobile application, and I want the app to run in background without user intervention of launching the app.

Could someone advise on how to proceed with this ? Or anyone who has ever done this in Xamarin Forms before ?

Note that the target device is Android and iOS.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: This can't be done on iOS. On Android there are some possibilities you have, but I think the best thing to do here is double-check your requirements and see if there is another way to solve your problem.

Comment: Hello, I do not think this question should be marked as duplicate. The difference here is I am looking for it to be done in Xamarin forms. On iOS, I agree as of now it is not achievable.

Comment: You don't do it in Forms.  You do it in the Android project, just as described in the duplicate link.

Comment: @Jason : I agree. But the code should be C#-based

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935764/how-can-i-make-c-sharp-xamarin-android-app-run-at-phone-start-up

Comment: Thanks @Jason. How can I achieve this in my PCL ? 
I want to make use of Dependency service.

Comment: this is by definition an Android specific function, so just put it in the Android app

Comment: @Jason : I am bit confused about the code. I have never implemented an android specific function like that. 

I have an app `DietRunner`. How can I direct this to be launched on device boot-up and keep running in the background? Please help if you could fit this in the link you provided.